# 深層学習のモデルを使ったアプリケーションの作成方法

Tags: 機械学習, 深層学習, 画像処理

デスクトップアプリケーションとして配布を考えています。
その際、画像や音声を入力にディープラーニングのモデルを利用する予定です。
pyinstaller のようなPython コードを実行ファイルへ変換するのではなく
C++やC# などの言語ですべての処理をローカルのGPU(AMD,Nvidia)上で実行するソフトウェアの開発を行う予定です。

Tensorflow やPytochのモデルをどのようなバックエンドを利用してモデルを実行すればよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlowやPyTorchでONNXを作成すると推論用の各種フレームワークを使えます。
それぞれ対応しているOSやGPUなどのアクセラレータがあるのでどれを使うべきかは詳細次第になります。
https://onnx.ai/supported-tools.html#deployModel

他にもTensorFlowにもPyTorchにもC++用ライブラリがあるので、フレームワーク固有の機能を使いたい場合は、推論時にもTensorFlowやPyTorchを使うことも出来ますが、今のところCUDA以外の対応に難があります。